# Determine position in front of quaternion with GLM?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, quaternions, glm-math

Is there a way to calculate the XYZ position in front of a quaternion (XYZW) rotation, preferably using [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)?

I know the Quat rotation and the Position of the object I want to calculate the position in front of.

I know how to calculate the position in front of a rotation matrix where you have a Front vector, Up vector and Right vector, but in this case I only have XYZW values (where W is always 0, I never see it becomming 1..?)

In very short:
The data I have: `Quat (X Y Z W)` and `Position(X Y Z)` and I want to calculate `PositionInFront(Position, Quat, Distance, &X, &Y, &Z)`

How to accomplish this goal?

I tried a cast to 3x3matrix and perform the Up,Right,Front (because a 3x3 matrix cast is these values, right?) calculations but they do not return the correct positions.

Or would it be possible to determine the objects Z Angle? (rotation around world Z / height axis only)

Comment: Uh, axis of the quaternion (xyz) is the direction vector.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Could you explain a little more? I don't understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that there were 2 more quaternion structures for the vehicle which I forgot to use. and those 3 are the complete set needed for the Front,Right,Up calculation formula:

```
    float offX = 10.0f;
    float offY = 0.0f;
    float offZ = 0.0f;

    float x = offX * info.Rotation.Front.x + offY * info.Rotation.Right.x + offZ * info.Rotation.Up.x + info.Pos.x;
    float y = offX * info.Rotation.Front.y + offY * info.Rotation.Right.y + offZ * info.Rotation.Up.y + info.Pos.y;
    float z = offX * info.Rotation.Front.z + offY * info.Rotation.Right.z + offZ * info.Rotation.Up.z + info.Pos.z;

    float Angle = (atan2(x-info.Pos.x, y-info.Pos.y) * 180.0f / PI);
```